# How can a goat companion get secondary natural attacks using feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, animal-companions, natural-weapon, unarmed-combat

Our group goat mascot / animal companion could use some additional natural attack forms for additional damage types right now (and definitely by 9th level when it gets Multiattack). He only has a primary Gore attack currently, but the GM is letting us assign the three feats he would have got for levels 1-5.

[Inspired / based on this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105374/12467)

I'd rather stay away from Evolved Companion if possible because the character with the companion has already spent those feat slots and won't get another until 7th level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animal companion Multiattack is actually a bit better than the feat. It allows creatures—like goats—that have only one or two natural attacks to use their primary attack twice in a full attack, albeit at a –5 penalty. And when a creature—again, such as a goat—has only one primary attack, that attack gets 1½ Str to damage, and such weapons also deal 50% more damage from Power Attack. This can mean it is more effective to beef up that one attack than it is to try to get more.

Part of the reason for that is because there just aren’t many options here for getting more attacks with just feats and magic items. Evolved Companion can be taken by the companion’s master to get a 1-point evolution, which offers many options for more attacks, but as you say, that is the master’s feats, not the companion’s—quite a bit more expensive. Other than that, though, there isn’t really much.

Comment: Can it buy Multiattack as a feat (and just choose a different feat when it would get Multiattack free later)? I notice a prerequisite of "three or more natural attacks" which a goat does not meet :(

Comment: @Gavin42 See the rules for [animal companions’ multiattack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions/#TOC-Multiattack): “If it does not have the requisite three or more natural attacks, the animal companion instead gains a second attack with its primary natural weapon, albeit at a –5 penalty.” This is a feature of the animal companion “class” feature multiattack, which is slightly different from the feat of the same name (and that animal companions get as a bonus feat if they meet the requirements).

Comment: @Gavin42 There is no feat that does what this feature does for creatures with one or two natural attacks, though I feel it probably would not be an unreasonable feat to add. Feats gained as bonus feats are usually not replaced with another if the creature already has it, but many tables allow that as a houserule.

Comment: I was looking at the line of feats that grant extra attacks on certain conditions (like elephant stomp), but ultimately the answer wasn't good enough. I completely forgot that the animal companion also gains an additional attack.